# Button not responding in a android app

Tags: android

I'm developing a mobile app in android, and I'm using Httpost to get information from a web service but it's not the problem, the problem is that I put the action on a button but it never works this is my example of code

any solution ?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    setTitle("Connexion");

    email = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.password);
    cnx = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);


    cnx.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {

    String em = email.getText().toString();
    String ps = password.getText().toString();
    String url = getString(R.string.serveur);

    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", em));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", ps));

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url+"/UserLogin");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = reader.readLine();
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        is.close();

          /***************************/
          /* Résultats de la requête */
          /***************************/

         String result = sb.toString();
         JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);

         System.out.println(jObj);
         System.out.println("karim");
    }

    catch(Exception e) {}           

    }       

    });

}
```

}

Comment: You may want to read this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you click the button. Anyway, I think Network Activity on the UI thread isn't allowed from Android 3.0 and above. You'll have to do that with an Async task now. Also don't forget to add the required permissions in your manifest :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where's your AsyncTask class?

So you need to have a class which extends AsyncTask class

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", params[0]));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[1]));

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[2]+"/UserLogin");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = reader.readLine();
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        is.close();

          /***************************/
          /* Résultats de la requête */
          /***************************/

         String result = sb.toString();
         JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);

         System.out.println(jObj);
         System.out.println("karim");

        return ""; 
    }

    catch(Exception e) {}           
         return "Error thrown";
    }       



            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                // might want to play with the returned string passed
                // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {}

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
        }
    }
```

And your `onClick` should look like this

```
cnx.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
           String em = email.getText().toString();
           String ps = password.getText().toString();
           String url = getString(R.string.serveur);
           new LongOperation().execute(em, ps, url);
}


});
```

And make sure you have internet permission in AndroidManifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: in you're LongOperation class you're missing a return statement

Comment: thanks but you're sure that it have to be before the catch not after. it's a return statement for the doInBackgroun function